# Why do I get an error when using JToken.Value() method?

Tags: c#, json

The GetValue method below receives the data for the passed in symbol in JSON format and uses the Newtonsoft.Json library to convert the data into a dynamic object. The TryGetValue method is to get the value of the field name, passed in as a parameter, from the JSON data. Finally, I return the data if the field is valid, but if the field is not valid, I return an error message.

```
private string GetValue(string symbol, string field)
{
   string json = HttpGet(symbol, field);
   dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
   var quote = obj.query.results.quote;

   JToken returnValue = null;
   quote.TryGetValue(field, out returnValue);
   if (returnValue != null)
        return returnValue.Value();

   return field + " is not a valid field name.";
}
```

My problem is in the line below, I get the error "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'key' of 'JToken.Value(object)":

```
return returnValue.Value();
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: What does the `json` string look like?  What string should the method return?  Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: Were missing some details as you are using a `dynamic` type. Makes this difficult to debug for you

Comment: @dbc I'm sorry but I'm a bit new to this entire thing. To keep things simple, I am trying to create an Excel RTD server which gets the information from Yahoo finance API. I've replicated my code from this link: https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2014/09/25/integrate-excel-rtd-yahoo-web-service/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this article](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2014/09/25/integrate-excel-rtd-yahoo-web-service/) is a little bit outdated. The Newtonsoft.Json library did have updates over the past years. The function value in JToken became generic. From `string JToken.Value();` to `T JToken.Value<T>();`. You basically say to the compiler that the return value is a string.

In your case your can fix your code with:

```
private string GetValue(string symbol, string field)
{
   string json = HttpGet(symbol, field);
   dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
   var quote = obj.query.results.quote;

   JToken returnValue = null;
   quote.TryGetValue(field, out returnValue);
   if (returnValue != null)
        return returnValue.Value<string>();

   return field + " is not a valid field name.";
}
```

I tested this code while I was assuming that the following json came back from HttpGet(symbol, field)

```
    string field = "Test";
    string json = "{ \"query\": { \"results\": { \"quote\": { \"Test\": \"Random\" } } } }";
```